# Pattern matching in Scala and variables

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm new to Scala and was a little bit wondering of how pattern matching works. Imagine I have the following:

```
case class Cls(i: Int)

case b @ Cls(i) => //Ok
case e : Cls => //Ok
case f @ Cls => //Ok
case s: Cls(i) =>  //compile error
case str: String => //ok
```

I do not quite understand where to use `@` and where to use `:`. Is there some strictly defined rule?

Comment: There are some nice examples written by the community here -  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/661/pattern-matching#t=201703201610568171377, they might help you as well :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@` when you want to bind the entire matched type to a value, but also want to bind individual elements inside the type. This means that:

```
case b @ Cls(i) =>
```

Will assign `b` to the reference of `Cls`, such that you can access the `i` value via `b.i`. It will also bind `i` to the first argument of the constructor pattern, which is of type `Int`. This is useful when you need to evaluate individual values of the type but also need the entire reference to the class, i.e:

```
case b @ Cls(i) => if (i > 10) b else b.copy(i = 10)
```

If you only want to bind the entire reference of `Cls` to a fresh value, use `:`

```
case e: Cls =>
```

This binds the reference to `Cls` to `e`.

If we want to get a bit more formal, `case f @ Cls` is called [Pattern Binders](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-binders):

> A pattern binder `x @ p` consists of a pattern variable `x` and a pattern
>   `p`. The type of the variable `x` is the static type `T` of the pattern
>   `p`. This pattern matches any value `v` matched by the pattern `p`,
>   provided the run-time type of `v` is also an instance of `T`, and it
>   binds the variable name to that value.

And `case c: Cls` is called [Typed Patterns](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#typed-patterns):

> A typed pattern `x:T` consists of a pattern variable `x` and a type
>   pattern `T`. The type of `x` is the type pattern `T`, where each type
>   variable and wildcard is replaced by a fresh, unknown type. This
>   pattern matches any value matched by the type pattern `T`; it binds the
>   variable name to that value

Comment: If you are new to Scala, maybe have a look at Extractors. Via the apply and unapply methods you can define how the Pattern-Matching behaves.

Answer (score 1):

@ is called as binding operator, in pattern matching we use for name binding, it Basically stores the instance with the matched pattern, so that you can use the instance letter in the following expressions.

example

```
    case class Person(name: String, id: Int)
    val p1 = new Person("xxxx", 10)
    
    val result = p1 match {
                           case x1 @ Person(n,i) => s"for object $x1 name is ${x1.person} and id ${i}"
                           case _ => "Wrong Object type"
    }

    println(result)
```

Output:- for object Person(xxxx, 10) name is xxxx and id 10

Note here we stored p1 object reference in x1 variable thus we can extract name and id in two ways
1st way - m x1.name or x1.id

2nd way -  $n or $i